# How to find out rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I need to make some minor changes in a rails project but in order to test it locally I will need to run a rails server.

I downloaded the map structure but there is no gemfile to be found.

How can I find out the rails version of the application so I can make a new project and copy the files over so I can start a WEBrick server.

This is the file structure I got; http://i.gyazo.com/d9ad43029078428dec21456b1301cc91.png

I can guesstimate the version since it was deployed in 2010 but is that normal that rails didnt have a gemfile back then?

Thank you.

Comment: Any chance there are bundled gems in a vendor folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was normal back then. Check your `config/environment.rb`. Rails version should be there somewhere, probably in `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` constant or something similar.

**EDIT**: also, you can probably install all required gems with `rake gems:install`.

Comment: Can I just get the project locally and run that? That would be so much easier.

Comment: Yes. Think of it as a way to do what Bundler does today.